# angular-block-ui doesn't execute my html as a custom message

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to block my UI and show a spinner while it is blocked.

I tried to use the following :

```js
blockUI.start("<div class='dots-loader'>Minions are Working!</div>");

// some code that fetches data from server

blockUI.stop();
```

here 'dots-loader' is taken from the css provided by : http://www.css-spinners.com

on suceess, it does block the ui and display the message, but it displays my html as text.

is there any way to achieve this spinner thing inside the blockUI custom message??

Comment: I also face same problem I need a solution like you...blockUI.start() showing only text .To display loading spinner I thing another approach should be followed.

Answer (score 0):

although this is not a good solution to customize a library file but I have to do this to achieve loading image instead Loading text.Because angular-block-ui.ng.html has only Loading.. see below link

https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui/blob/master/src/angular-block-ui/angular-block-ui.ng.html

here the html

```
<div class="block-ui-overlay"></div>
<div class="block-ui-message-container" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="block-ui-message" ng-class="$_blockUiMessageClass">
 {{ state.message }}</div>
</div>
```

in your project open angular-block-ui.js file or min file. go to below the file and found this code below.

```
// Automatically generated.
// This file is already embedded in your main javascript output, there's no need to include this file
// manually in the index.html. This file is only here for your debugging pleasures.
angular.module('blockUI').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache){
  $templateCache.put('angular-block-ui/angular-block-ui.ng.html', '<div class=\"block-ui-overlay\"></div><div class=\"block-ui-message-container\" aria-live=\"assertive\" aria-atomic=\"true\"><div class=\"block-ui-message\" ng-class=\"$_blockUiMessageClass\">{{ state.message }}</div></div>');
}]);
```

now add your code `<div class='dots-loader'>Minions are Working!</div>`
after {{state.message}} finally it look like .

```
 $templateCache.put('angular-block-ui/angular-block-ui.ng.html', '<div class=\"block-ui-overlay\"></div><div class=\"block-ui-message-container\" aria-live=\"assertive\" aria-atomic=\"true\"><div class=\"block-ui-message\" ng-class=\"$_blockUiMessageClass\">{{ state.message }}
<div class='dots-loader'>Minions are Working!</div></div></div>');
    }]);
```

then just give a blank space text

```
blockUI.start(' ');
```

hope you will find better solution. Thanks